# CasperJS / PhantomJS jQuery Multifile issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs, multifile-uploader

I using PhantomJS 1.9.2 (because 2.0 version hse problems with attaching files).

I have an issue with uploading files via a form that using JQuery multifile.

For some reason PhantomJS can't upload any files via form like this.

I have tried to reproduce this issue in a simple environment - such as this site http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile/

Here's the code:

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});

casper.start('http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile/', function() {
    this.page.uploadFile('input#MultiFile9', 'C:/test.jpg');
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('output.png');
});

casper.run();
```

Is there any solution for this?